# Qt Creator project using CMake : Issues removing files

Tags: c++, qt, cmake

So here's a quick (and probably inane) question from someone new to CMake and Qt.

I'm currently using Qt Creator, alongside of CMake, to create some project. I have 2 C++ files that I have to remove that are no longer used anywhere within the codebase. I have removed them from the project, the CMakeLists.txt file, nuked the build and qt_build directories, and proceeded to try to rebuild. However, I seem to be getting an warning when running qmake which looks like this...

```
15:03:03: Running steps for project Traveler...
15:03:03: Starting: "C:\Qt\5.9.2\msvc2017_64\bin\qmake.exe" C:\Users\someone\Traveler\Traveler.pro -spec win32-msvc "CONFIG+=debug" "CONFIG+=qml_debug"**    
Info: creating stash file C:\...\build-traveler-Desktop_Qt_5_9_2_MSVC2017_64bit-Debug\.qmake.stash
    WARNING: Failure to find: src\XX_Exceptions.cpp
    WARNING: Failure to find: include\XX_Exceptions.hpp
    WARNING: Failure to find: src\XX_Exceptions.cpp
    WARNING: Failure to find: include\XX_Exceptions.hpp
    15:03:07: The process "C:\Qt\5.9.2\msvc2017_64\bin\qmake.exe" exited normally.
    15:03:07: Starting: "C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe" qmake_all
```

It seems as if qmake exits without error, but I really don't like seeing these compiler warnings (especially duplicated, so its showing up in two places).

Then, when I proceed to try to build...

```
15:16:27: Running steps for project Traveler...
15:16:27: Configuration unchanged, skipping qmake step.
15:16:27: Starting: "C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe" 
    C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe -f Makefile.Debug
Error: dependent 'src\XX_Exceptions.cpp' does not exist.
jom: C:\Users\someone\build-Traveler-Desktop_Qt_5_9_2_MSVC2017_64bit-Debug\Makefile [debug] Error 2
15:16:28: The process "C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project Traveler (kit: Desktop Qt 5.9.2 MSVC2017 64bit)
The kit Desktop Qt 5.9.2 MSVC2017 64bit has configuration issues which might be the root cause for this problem.
When executing step "Make"
```

**Question** :: Is there any location where the specific files in the project are referenced besides the CMakeLists after I nuke the build directories?

Comment: Did you get rid of the intermediate object files too? (clean the project) ? Did you run CMake after making the changes?

Comment: If possible, use `qmake` for Qt projects; `cmake` support in Creator was/is lacking, and you'll have to set up many Qt specific details yourself.